# Open Google Chrome in another display

Tags: google-chrome, vnc-server

I have problem with running Google Chrome in specified display:

```
vncserver :11 -geometry 1024x2000
google-chrome --display :11
```

`vncerver` starts fine, bot browser runs in current display, not the `:11`. Below some logs:

```
New 'localhost:11 (hsz)' desktop is localhost:11

Starting applications specified in /home/hsz/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/hsz/.vnc/freedomes:11.log
```

<kbd>/home/hsz/.vnc/freedomes:11.log</kbd>

```
Xvnc TigerVNC 1.3.1 - built Mar 20 2014 13:14:03
Copyright (C) 1999-2011 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.txt)
See http://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.
Underlying X server release 11500000, The X.Org Foundation

Initializing built-in extension VNC-EXTENSION
Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
Initializing built-in extension XTEST
Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
Initializing built-in extension SYNC
Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
Initializing built-in extension RENDER
Initializing built-in extension RANDR
Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
Initializing built-in extension RECORD
Initializing built-in extension DPMS
Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
Initializing built-in extension XVideo
Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
Initializing built-in extension GLX

Fri Jun 13 12:24:32 2014
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on all interface(s), port 5911
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0

Fri Jun 13 12:24:44 2014
 Connections: accepted: 127.0.0.1::50815
 SConnection: Client needs protocol version 3.8
 SConnection: Client requests security type VeNCrypt(19)
 VNCSConnST:  Server default pixel format depth 24 (32bpp) little-endian rgb888
```

<kbd>google-chrome --display :11</kbd>

```
[6658:6658:0613/122602:ERROR:nss_util.cc(853)] After loading Root Certs, loaded==false: NSS error code: -8018
Created new window in existing browser session.
```

After calling:

```
DISPLAY=localhost:11.0 google-chrome
```

I get:

```
[7212:7212:0613/123350:ERROR:nss_util.cc(853)] After loading Root Certs, loaded==false: NSS error code: -8018
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display "localhost:11.0".
[7242:7242:0613/123351:ERROR:gl_surface_glx.cc(407)] glxQueryVersion failed
[7242:7242:0613/123351:ERROR:gl_surface_x11.cc(56)] GLSurfaceGLX::InitializeOneOff failed.
[7242:7242:0613/123351:ERROR:gpu_child_thread.cc(132)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
Created new window in existing browser session.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify which display to use using the DISPLAY environment variable.

Use the following snippet:

```
# export DISPLAY=localhost:11.0
# google-chrome --disable-webgl
```

The VNC server does not support OpenGL extensions. The `--disable-webgl` is to make sure Chrome doesn't try to use OpenGL/WebGL.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I get an error - look at the bottom of my question please.

Comment: It is probably caused by Chrome trying to use OpenGL/WebGL. You can try disabling it from the profile, or use the command line option.

Comment: `--disable-webgl` not works - it still requires `GLX`. `Google Chrome 35.0.1916.153 `

Comment: @hsz have you tried disabling WebGL from the profile, this can be found under `about:flags` and then "Disable WebGL".

Comment: Yes - with no luck. Looks like this flag is ignored.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm out of ideas then. I think it's a step in the right direction though. Perhaps you can start a new question/rephrase your question using this new problem. There is also a similar question on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/430919/getting-webgl-to-run-on-an-amazon-ec2-server).

Answer (score 0):

This works as of Chromium 59.0.3071.86

Check existing VNC sessions

```
vncserver -list                                                                                                                                           
TigerVNC server sessions:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
X DISPLAY #     PROCESS ID                                                                                                                     
:1              20013
```

Execute chromium as

```
DISPLAY=:1.0 chromium
```